# Sparql Insert Exception : SPARQLWrapper.SPARQLExceptions.QueryBadFormed

Tags: python, sparql, semantic-web, sparqlwrapper

I have been having this weird issue, I am trying to insert into a virtuoso graph using SPARQLWrapper library in python. 
I am able to insert a triple via the browser based endpoint at `localhost:8890\sparql` , but when I try the same query via my python SparqlWrapper it throws the below error:

> SPARQLWrapper.SPARQLExceptions.QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: a bad
>   request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is
>   bad formed.

I feel there is something wrong at configuration end, but failed to identify the same.

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> Insert Data  { GRAPH <test> { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/life> <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Artist> '2' . } }
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(process.run("1"))
  File "test.py", line 27, in run
    result = self.sparql.query().convert()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 390, in query
    return QueryResult(self._query())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 363, in _query
    raise QueryBadFormed()
SPARQLWrapper.SPARQLExceptions.QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is bad formed.
```

Comment: Is there a query, or are you using an empty string? ;)  Please show your SPARQL query.  There are query validators at http://sparql.org that you can use to check whether your query is well-formed, by the way.  But please include the query, since "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself."

Comment: Apologies, Added the query!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take this to the sparql.org's [SPARQL update validator](http://sparql.org/update-validator.html), it will tell you immediately that this is wrong, and where the syntax error is:

> #### Input:
>
> ```
>   1 PREFIX xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
>   2 PREFIX rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
>   3 PREFIX rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
>   4 PREFIX owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
>   5 PREFIX fn:      <http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions#>
>   6 PREFIX apf:     <http://jena.hpl.hp.com/ARQ/property#>
>   7 
>   8 PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
>   9 Insert Data Into GRAPH <test> {
>  10   <http://dbpedia.org/resource/life> <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Artist> '2'^^xsd:integer .
>  11 }
> ```
>
> #### Syntax error:
>
> ```
> Encountered " "into" "Into "" at line 9, column 13.
> Was expecting:
>     "{" ...
> ```

Of course, to find out how to do what you're trying to do, you'll need to look to the spec.  The [SPARQL 1.1 Update](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insert) is the place to look, and while I'd advise you to skim through that to get a good idea of what's in there, one example will be enough to show what you need to write:

> #### Example 2:
>
> This SPARQL 1.1 Update request adds a triple to provide the price of a
>   book. As opposed to the previous example, which affected the default
>   graph, the requested change happens in the named graph identified by
>   the IRI `http://example/bookStore`.
>
> ```
> PREFIX dc: <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/>
> PREFIX ns: <http://example.org/ns#>
> INSERT DATA
> { GRAPH <http://example/bookStore> { <http://example/book1>  ns:price  42 } }
> ```

Your query needs to be

```
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
Insert Data 
{ GRAPH <test> { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/life> <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Artist> '2'^^xsd:integer . } }
```

Comment: Josh Some how still the same error, also i tried the same code with two versions of virtuoso 6 and 7 respectively, much to my surprise my old code is working fine with version 7.x but throws the above error with 6.x

Comment: PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> Insert Data { GRAPH <test> { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/life> <http://umbel.org/umbel/rc/Artist> '2' . }}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 37, in <module>
    sys.exit(process.run("1"))
  File "test.py", line 31, in run
    result = self.sparql.query().convert()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 390, in query

Comment: return QueryResult(self._query())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/SPARQLWrapper/Wrapper.py", line 363, in _query
    raise QueryBadFormed()
SPARQLWrapper.SPARQLExceptions.QueryBadFormed: QueryBadFormed: a bad request has been sent to the endpoint, probably the sparql query is bad formed.

Comment: @AnkitSolanki It's next to impossible to read code in comments.  Please post this as an update to your question.  Also, I very much doubt that it's the _same_ error.  I see, for instance, `PREFIX dbpedia: <dbpedia.org/resource/>;` with a final semicolon (which was _not_ in the query that I posted) that doesn't belong there.  You may be getting the same _local_ error, but it's because of a different syntax error.

Comment: @AnkitSolanki And that semicolon isn't the only one;  I see that other sneaked in in other places, and your datatype on `'2'` is gone.  **Please** post code as updates.  Also, please validate your queries with sparql.org first.

Comment: @AnkitSolanki That said, I _did_ have a missing brace in my answer (which I've now fixed).  Either of us could have spotted that by using the query validator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43351/discussion-between-ankit-solanki-and-joshua-taylor)

Comment: pinged you on chat, also i tried the same code with other packages its working fine!

Comment: @AnkitSolanki As I said, there _was_ an error in the code that I posted, but I've updated it now.  Do note that SPARQL Update is a part of a later SPARQL revision (1.1).  It looks like SPARQL Update 1.1 support was added in Virtuoso 7 (see [this announcement](http://www.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/#2013-08-05: New VOS 7.0.0 Released)), so it's not surprising if it doesn't work in earlier versions.

Comment: Yup this confirms the same too : http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=CAKZ-WGfuh5gDywtC4vZR72km6noOB-ZRQmfwoOzHB6q%2BYAvUsA%40mail.gmail.com&forum_name=sparql-wrapper-devel

Answer (score 0):

I spent all day battling this problem. I finally found the solution to my version of this problem:

Make sure that your spaces are actually spaces and not just newlines "\n". The editors have no problem with this, SPARQLWrapper doesn't like it.