# Questions about Cloud + GraphDB

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

I'm working on a project and i need a triple-store database in cloud, which support SPARQL queries.

1. GraphDB looks good and works fine in my desktop computer (localhost). But, when I try to use it in the cloud (**[CloudDB](https://cloud.ontotext.com)**), REST requisitions doesn't work.

   Problem: I'm trying to query my repository using REST, by `curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/sparql-results+xml'`.

   Repository ID: `hermesiot`

   **Query:** `select * where {?s ?p ?o .} limit 100`

   **Results:**

   Response Code: `404`

   Response Body: `{"message":"Database not found."}`
2. How to **deploy** GraphDB in cloud solutions, like Azure or another free solutions?

Many thanks :)

Comment: (1) Please ask one question at a time. (2) Please [reformulate your question #1, and reconsider whether #2 is appropriate for this website](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [official example](http://docs.s4.ontotext.com/display/S4docs/cURL#cURL-SemanticGraphDatabaseasaService), your query should be of this kind:

```
 curl --header 'Accept: application/sparql-results+xml' \
      --data "query=SELECT+*+{?s+?p+?o.}" \
      --user s472kd733007:bhrfk1aa8o0qlj7 \
      'https://rdf.s4.ontotext.com/4032537848/wikidata/repositories/fast'
```

However, the query above does not work for me, whereas the query below does:

```
 curl --header 'Accept: application/sparql-results+xml' \
      --data "query=SELECT+*+{?s+?p+?o.}" \
      --user s472kd733007:bhrfk1aa8o0qlj7 \
      'http://awseb-e-m-awsebloa-11laimnu18r2i-2106042490.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/4032537848/wikidata/repositories/fast'
```

In the queries above:

- `s472kd733007` — API key,
- `bhrfk1aa8o0qlj7`— API key secret,
- `4032537848` — user id
- `wikidata` — database name,
- `fast` — repository id,
- `http://awseb-e-m-awsebloa-...eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com` — AWS instance address.

Visit tabs in your dashboard in order to obtain applicable values of these parameters.

[image: dashboard]

---

As for update queries, see e. g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46283806/7879193). Your query should be:

```
curl --header 'Accept: application/sparql-results+xml' \
      --data "update=INSERT+DATA+{owl:Nothing+owl:Nothing+owl:Nothing}" \
      --user s472kd733007:bhrfk1aa8o0qlj7 \
      'http://awseb-e-m-awsebloa-11laimnu18r2i-2106042490.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/4032537848/wikidata/repositories/fast/statements'
```

Please note that endpoint address in this request is different.

Comment: Work fine.

In case i want to do a update query, sould be:

Comment: @MaykeFerreira, I have update my answer, now it contains an update query example.