# How to write code in C #, to add new data to the database

Tags: c#, sparql, rdf, graphdb, dotnetrdf

Adding triplets to GraphDB

```
SparqlRemoteEndpoint endpoint = new SparqlRemoteEndpoint(new Uri("http://localhost:7200/sparql"), "http://localhost:7200/");
SparqlResultSet results = endpoint.QueryWithResultSet("PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/> INSERT DATA {:test :test :hhrh }");
```

why does not it work?

```
StardogConnector stardog = new StardogConnector("http://localhost:7200", "test", "admin", "posw");
stardog.Begin();
string query = "PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/>SELECT * WHERE {:" + line[0] + " ?k :" + line[1] + "}";
stardog.Query(query);
stardog.Commit();
```

another way, same problem. Created a DB on a lokalka

---

Yes, I also came to this conclusion, I use GraphDB for the first time. Well, how can I implement it with a file? I wrote such code.

```
IGraph g = new Graph();

string sql = "PREFIX : <http://www.example.org/> INSERT DATA {:test :test :hhrh }";
g.LoadFromFile("t.n3"); 

Object results = g.ExecuteQuery(sql);
```

here comes such an error

```
VDS.RDF.Parsing.RdfParseException
HResult = 0x80131500
Message = [InsertKeywordToken at Line 1 Column 36 to Line 1 Column 42] Unexpected Token encountered - expected a BASE / PREFIX directive or a Query Keyword to start a Query
Source = dotNetRDF
Stack trace:
in VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlQueryParser.ParseInternal (SparqlQueryParserContext context)
in VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlQueryParser.ParseInternal (TextReader input)
in VDS.RDF.Parsing.SparqlQueryParser.ParseFromString (String queryString)
in VDS.RDF.GraphExtensions.ExecuteQuery (IGraph g, String sparqlQuery)
in algorAutoText.Program.Main (String [] args) in C: \ Users \ Denis \ source \ repos \ algorAutoText \ algorAutoText \ Program.cs: line 43
```

judging by mistake, I supposedly did not add BASE / PREFIX. But he is in the request

Comment: " same problem"...what problem exactly? You need to tell us the problem before we can try to fix it!

Comment: ` VDS.RDF.Query.RdfQueryException
HResult=0x80131500
Сообщение = A HTTP Error occurred while trying to make the SPARQL Query, see inner exception for details
Источник = dotNetRDF
Трассировка стека:
в VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(ISparqlResultsHandler handler, String sparqlQuery)
в VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet(String sparqlQuery)
в algorAutoText.Program.Main(String[] args) в C:\Users\Денис\source\repos\Program.cs:строка 98

Внутреннее исключение 1:
WebException: Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (404) Не найден.`

Comment: Ok thanks but: 1) Please put the details into your original question. Code, error messages, details etc do not belong in the comments. You can use the "edit" button (just under the blue "c#" and "rdf" tags) to change your question and add this information. 2) Please translate any exception messages into English, as this is an English-speaking site only. (P.S. If you speak Russian, there is also a [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) you can use instead, if you prefer.)

Comment: Anyway from as much as I can see, your request to localhost:7200 seems to be returning a 404 Not Found error. This means your URL is wrong, or that the sparql server is not installed properly. Unfortunately we cannot see your environment, so it's not easy for us to know what the correct URL should be, or how the server is configured.

Comment: Most likely, the main problem is wrong URI. See e.g. this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46283806/7879193

Comment: wrong request URL, please read the docs

Comment: My code does not accept ""SparqlResultSet"" for writing, what should I use instead?

Comment: writing to what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update and delete queries come through the /statements endpoint,

i.e. `/repositories/{repository_id}/statements`.

You can see the RDF4J server REST API here:

http://docs.rdf4j.org/rest-api/#_the_rdf4j_server_rest_api

Answer (score 0):

When you use the DELETE or INSERT keywords you are doing a SPARQL **Update**, not a Query. SPARQL separates Query and Update into two separate specifications and most triple stores implement them as two separate endpoints (e.g. for security reasons).

To do an update from dotNetRDF into a triple store you have two options.

1. You can work directly with the SPARQL update endpoint in which case you will need to check the documentation for your triple store to find out how to create the URL for that - see https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Updating-With-SPARQL#remote-updates for details.
2. Alternatively if your triple store is one of the ones supported by dotNetRDF (Stardog and Sesame/GraphDB both are), then there are convenience wrappers that make this a bit easier - for more information about this please refer to https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/UserGuide-Triple-Store-Integration#update